# Trouble with getting thread to sleep - Android

Tags: handler, sleep, runnable

I'm pretty new to java (first post) and trying to make a loop that does the following:

Post to a textview, Wait, Post to another textview, Wait, Clear both (by posting " " to each one), Sleep, Repeat loop.

The loop send the messages to the que almost instantaneously, without doing the sleep part inbetween

```
           Runnable postRight = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    right_side.setText("post right");
                                           }
                };

            Runnable postLeft = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    left_side.setText("post left");
                }
            };


            Runnable clear = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    left_side.setText(" ");
                    right_side.setText(" ");
                }
            };
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
            while (i < 3) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Entered  while");

                long Timer =  SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                handler.postAtTime(postLeft, Timer + 1000);
                Log.i(TAG, "post left");

                handler.postAtTime(postRight, Timer + 2000);
                Log.i(TAG, "postright");

                handler.postAtTime(clear, Timer + 3000);
                Log.i(TAG, "clear");

                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "inside runnable");
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the thread t is sleeping, but it's its own thread, so the main thread just keeps on going after initiating and the main thread never sleeps